# Stretchable/expandable vertically aligned text (relative to image)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I would like to place some text next to an image where the text is vertically aligned relative to the image. However, I do not know how wide the window will be and so I would like the text container to expand to fill the available space.

I have tried simply putting vertical-align:middle on the text container. That kind of works, but the text will wrap below the image if the text is too long. In order to combat this, I used display:inline-block on the text container. However, this then puts the whole text container below the image!

So far, I have something like this:

```
<span><img src="img.gif" /></span>
<span style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle">Text goes here</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The span element wrapping the image should have the same style applied.